# EPS not deducted by some employers but some have deducted

Tags: india, pension, epf

I started my service in 2012, EPF and EPS both were deducted. Later I closed this EPF account and withdred money from EPF, EPS still shows amount.

Then when I switched organisations till 2018 EPS was deducted.

Later from 2019 onwards only EPF was deducted. EPS was not deducted till now.

Now in 2024 I switched again, and my current employer is asking whether to opt for EPS. Shall I enable EPS again ?

What are the consequences if in between EPS was not deducted and later again I enroll for it. Will it cause issues during EPF withdrawal and claims settlement ?

Thanks